# "Table is read-only. Search path mismatch" error in PhpStorm DB console view when try to edit any cell in Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, phpstorm

OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.16

PhpStorm: 2017.2.1

Postgres: 9.6.4

When I double click on any table and try to edit cell data everything works as it should, but when data is selected with query (ex.: `SELECT * FROM invoices`) then I get following tooltip with error.

Can anyone help me with information where should I configure/fix this? I'm not sure if this is PhpStorm or Postgres specific issue.

[image: Tooltip with error message]

Comment: Have a look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4989 and other tickets mentioned there -- looks similar. Comment there with your details. If your query is a simple one as `SELECT * FROM invoices` then it must be some PhpStorm issue.

Comment: Have you find out a solution ? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it by clicking on the synchronize button in database control toolbar

[image]

This refreshes the schema from distant database which may have changed and helps PHPStorm to properly bind data